# Firebase Rest Api setting language for user or app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase has option to set language code or app language for current user in order to get verification, password reset emails in defined language like below. below is from [Android SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users) implementation

> Additionally you can localize the verification email by updating the
>   language code on the Auth instance before sending the email. For
>   example:
>
> auth.setLanguageCode("fr"); // To apply the default app language
>   instead of explicitly setting it. // auth.useAppLanguage();

But i am using rest api within my uwp application and this option is not defined in rest api [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-send-email-verification)

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anybody else is looking for solution. you need to add header as  X-Firebase-Locale: 'fr'. C# code will look like as below. you can find the full implementation [here](https://github.com/EmilAlipiev/firebase-authentication-dotnet/blob/master/src/Firebase.Auth/FirebaseAuthProvider.cs)

```
public async Task SendEmailVerificationAsync(string firebaseToken, string locale = null)
{
    var content = $"{{\"requestType\":\"VERIFY_EMAIL\",\"idToken\":\"{firebaseToken}\"}}";

    var StringContent = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    if (locale != null)
        StringContent.Headers.Add("X-Firebase-Locale", locale);

    var response = await this.client.PostAsync(new Uri(string.Format(GoogleGetConfirmationCodeUrl, this.authConfig.ApiKey)), StringContent).ConfigureAwait(false);

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```